# Do all complex zeros of $Li_s(z)\,- \, Li_{1-s}(z)$ get the shape $s=\dfrac12 + \dfrac{k \, \pi }{\,\ln(2)}\,i$ when $z \rightarrow 0^{-}$?

Tags: number-theory, zeta-functions, polylogarithm

This is a subquestion of [this question on MO.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178620/are-all-complex-zeros-of-li-sz-pm-li-1-sz-on-the-critical-line-or)

Numerical evidence strongly suggests that when $z \rightarrow 0^{-}$ the complex zeros that lie in the critical strip $0 \lt \Re(s) < 1$ of:

$$Li_s(z)\,- \, Li_{1-s}(z)$$

all converge towards the shape $s=\dfrac12 + \dfrac{k \, \pi}{\,\ln(2)}i\, $ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Interested to understand whether this apparently trivial result could be derived from any known formulae for $Li_s(z)$ like:

$$Li_s(z) = \frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{(2\,\pi)^{1-s}} \left(i^{1-s}\,\zeta_H\left(1-s,\frac12+\frac{\ln(-z)}{2 \,\pi \, i}\right)+i^{s-1}\,\zeta_H\left(1-s,\frac12-\frac{\ln(-z)}{2 \,\pi \, i}\right)\right)$$

Thanks.

Comment: Try the power series.  All you need is $\operatorname{Li}_s(z) = z + 2^{-s}z^2 + O(z^3)$.

Comment: Thanks Antonio! That's it. Subtracting the power series at $z \rightarrow 0$ just reduces to $z^2(2^{−s}−2^{s−1})$. The result then immediately follows (and it also follows that these are the only roots and also none exist outside the strip). Much simpler than I thought...